# Property 'install' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'？

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Use `vue create` to create a project

run: vue-cli-service build --target lib --name index packages/index.ts --dest lib

output: Property 'install' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor'.

[image]
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
code:

```html
<template>
  <button class="my-button">button</button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyButton'
};
</script>
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　

<style scoped>
.my-button {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

```js
import Button from './src/index.vue';

Button.install = function (Vue) {
  Vue.component(Button.name, Button);
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? It seems like you're importing a VueConstructor Object that does not contains an Install Method, perhaps you should cast it or define it